# What typedef to use for 48bits vars

Tags: c, typedef, des

I don't really know the vocabulary here (bit vars? bit fields? bit strings?)

I'm coding an implementation of DES and I'm manipulating 64bits strings rarely, 28bits and 24bits a bit more, and 48 bits strings a lot.

I've seen implementations using arrays of chars. So it takes exactly the right amount of memory.

But when it comes to bit operation, I found using uint64_t typedef simplifying everything. Eventhough it's too much most of the time.

What do you guys think? Should I keep using uint64_t and pad it with 0s most of the time?

Comment: If space is _critical_ then bittwiddling arrays of chars might be ok.  Otherwise... don't.

Comment: @MooingDuck: `std::array`? In C?

Comment: `struct bit48 {char buffer[8];};` then

Answer (score 5):

You definitely want to use uint64_t for everything for performance and simplicity. If you need to handle 48-bit overflow you'll have to handle that specially.